# I am stuck with html/javascript webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to solve a problem and I quote: 
"A game needs to be created in which the user attempts to guess a random whole number between 1 and 100. Upon Guessing, the game will tell the user if they need to go higher or lower. If the user guesses the number, the game will tell them they’re right, and how many attempts it took"

I'm trying to attempt this by having a webpage with a prompt asking for the guess, and then if loops deciding if the guess is the same, higher or lower than the random number. However! I've got the prompt to show up, but no matter what number it will always say the numbers correct! Please help!

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="Assignment%20Task%202.js"></script>
<body>
PLAY THE GUESSING GAME:
Guess a number between 0 and 1000!
</body>
<br>
<button onclick= "Guessing_game()" >play</button>
<br>
<p>
    You have guessed this many times:
</p>
<p id="num_guesses"></p>
</html>
```

here's my javascript:

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
var num_guesses = 1;
function Guessing_game() {
    var guess;
    guess = prompt("what is your guess?");
    if (guess = number) {
        alert("Good Job! You got the number correct!");
    }
    if (guess < number) {
        num_guesses = +1;
        alert("Bad luck! You need to guess lower");
    }
    if (guess > number) {
        num_guesses = +1;
        alert("Bad luck! You need to guess higher");
    }
    document.getElementById("num_guesses").innerHTML = num_guesses;
}
```

Comment: guess = number just sets the guess to the number. You need to use guess == number

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `if (guess = number)` line of code.

Using `guess = number` assigns the number to the guess variable here. If you want to check whether **guess is equal to number** use `guess==number` in the if condition like:

`if (guess == number)`

For more information, you can read it out [here](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/5596c55d937676f6c80006c5).

Comment: thanks for your help, sorry knew to Javascript to the double equal sign got me, but now in my script it will only show "You need to guess lower" from, I've checked comparisons here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp so it doesn't seem to be a problem like earlier

Comment: @MrYummy No problem if you are new to javascript I am here to help you out but I did not understand your comment.

Comment: so the input used to say that every number was correct, which was fixed by putting in '=='. However now if you go down my 'if' loops in my javascript you will see
 if (guess < number) {
        num_guesses = +1;
        alert("Bad luck! You need to guess lower");
    }
this alert now shows for every input

Comment: it is happening as because you are using this line ` guess = prompt("what is your guess?");` which is wrong for the first if condition as because you are comparing the string with guess that is why the first second if condition is running which is guess<number

Comment: do one thing make some changes in the code as I suggest. Do take input from the user after the message `Enter your guess` is displayed and take another variable to store that input.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is assignment operator.

For e.g `var a = "foo";`

`==` is used for value comparison.

For e.g

```
if(a == "foo") {
  // Do something if above condition is true
 }
```

`===` is strict comparison, that means value and type should be same .

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, in javascript (and in many other languages):

- `=` is the assignment operator

But the best operator to use (especially in javascript) is ***not*** `==`.

- `==` indicates that two values are *equivalent*

Instead, the best operator to use is `===`:

- `===` indicates that two values are **identical**.

In this case, this is, ideally, what you ought to be using in your script:

```
if (guess === number) {

[... CODE HERE...]

}
```

Comment: Then you should be showing how to convert guess to a numeric value otherwise guess === number will always be false.